# Applying a function on every 3 columns (cols: 1-3, 4-6, 7-9) in dataframe

Tags: function, pandas, apply

I have the following DataFrame with multi-indexing:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaRJC.png)

What is the best way to apply mean/sum/avg function on each row , for each 3 columns: a b   c, then:  a1    b1  c1 and then a2  b2  c2 , so the result will be: in the example I did **sum**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24lpX.png)

Comment: can you provide a reproductible version of your dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `numpy array` and aggregate functions like `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

print (np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 3)
[0 0 0 1 1 1]

print (df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 3, axis=1).sum())
    0   1
0  12  13
1  15  10
2  18  14
```